# Call a 'helper' function from another component in React Native?

Tags: react-native, helper, react-native-router-flux

I'm sorry I find React Native to be hopelessly confusing and convoluted. I am using the code below as a 'helper' script to hold object values that could be accessed by separate components.

LogContext.js

```
import React, { useState } from 'react'

export const LogContext = React.createContext({
  set: "en",
  login: "false",
  setLog: () => {},
});

export const LogContextProvider = (props) => {

  const setLog = (login) => {
    setState({set: "jp", login: login, setLog});
  };

  const initState = {
    set: "en",
    login: "false",
    setLog,
  };

  const [state, setState] = useState(initState);

  return (
    <LogContext.Provider value={state}>
      {props.children}
    </LogContext.Provider>
  );
};
```

My issue is being able to call 'setLog' from another component in order to change the values of the 'state' object.  For example:

AnyOtherComponent.js

```
import React, { useState, useContext, createContext } from 'react'
import { Button, TouchableOpacity, Text } from 'react-native'
import { Actions } from 'react-native-router-flux'

import { LogContextProvider, LogContext } from './LogContext'

const AnyOtherComponent = (props) => {
  const status = useContext(LogContext);
  //status.setLog('true');  //also tried to call the 'update' here...

  const goToHome = () => {
  status.setLog('true');  //call doesn't update object values here either...
  Actions.home()
  }

   return (
   <>
     <Text>This is Proceed</Text>
     <Text>Passed SET: {JSON.stringify(status.set)}</Text>
     <Text>Passed LOGIN: {JSON.stringify(status.login)}</Text>
     <Button title="Update" onPress={goToHome} />
   </>
   )
}
export default AnyOtherComponent
```

Home.js

```
import React, { useState, useContext, createContext } from 'react'
import { Button, TouchableOpacity, Text } from 'react-native';
import { Actions } from 'react-native-router-flux';

import { LogContextProvider, LogContext } from './LogContext'

const Home = () => {
const status = useContext(LogContext);

   const goToAbout = () => {
      Actions.about()
   }
   const goToLogin = () => {
      Actions.login()
   }

   return (
     <LogContext.Provider value={status}>
      <TouchableOpacity style = {{ margin: 128 }} onPress = {goToAbout}>
         <Text>This is HOME!</Text>
         <Text>Passed SET: {JSON.stringify(status.set)}</Text>
         <Text>Passed LOGIN: {JSON.stringify(status.login)}</Text>
      </TouchableOpacity>
      {status.login === 'false' ? (
        <Button
          title="Go to Login"
          onPress={goToLogin}
        />
      ) : (
        <Button
          title="BroadCast"
          onPress={() => Actions.BroadCast()}
        />
      )}
     </LogContext.Provider>
   )
}
export default Home
```

I have also attempted using 'useEffect' without success (as indicated in the commented out lines).  In that case the error seems to be thrown relating to the navigation I am using (React-Native-Router-Flux).  Any advice greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You need to define your function that changes the state when creating de Context.
Make sure the shape of the default value passed to createContext matches the shape that the consumers expect!

```
export const LogContext = React.createContext({
  set: "en",
  login: "false",
  setLog: () => {},
});
```

State also contains the updater function so it will be passed down into the context provider!

```
export const LogContextProvider = (props) => {
  const setLog = (login) => {
    setState({ set: "jp", login: login, setLog });
  };

  const initState = {
    set: "en",
    login: "false",
    setLog,
  };
  const [state, setState] = useState(initState);

  return (
    <LogContext.Provider value={state}>{props.children}</LogContext.Provider>
  );
};
```

To consumer the context you can use Context.Consumer or useContext hooks.

```
// with Context.Consumer
<LogContext.Consumer>
  {status => <Button onPress={() => status.setLog(true)} />}
</LogContext.Consumer>

//with useContext
const status = useContext(LogContext);
<Button onPress={() => status.setLog(true)} />
```

For more details, React's documentation has a nice example of [how to updating Context from a component](https://reactjs.org/docs/context.html#updating-context-from-a-nested-component).

Comment: Thank you for the reply, much appreciated.  How do I call the 'setLog' from another component...?  Should I use "status.setLog({'true'})" as I have in my example?  Thanks again.

Comment: Looking at the link you provided, it seems I need to call using a "Consumer" that wraps within my 'return'. in the component that needs to change the object values..correct?

Comment: You can use both, Context.Consumer and useContext hooks. I updated de answer with examples.

Comment: Thank you for the help, I will give this a try when I can probably tomorrow.  One last question, if I may...can I call the function without using an "onPress" with a button?  I would like to call to update object values without user intervention...if possible...?  Regards.

Comment: Also shouldn't the "setLog" be passed with a parameter...?  For example "status.setLog('true')" instead of just "status.setLog"...?

Comment: Yes, you can use a arrow function: () => status.setLog(true), see example again. To use in another place is more simple with useContext(). Put in the top of your component and use it in any place.

Comment: Thanks for your help.  I have my "LogContext" adjusted as you suggest.  I have updated my code above.  The only issue is that I am still unable to update the 'login' value to "true", the routing to the 'Home' screen verifies this.  Is my call to 'setLog' within the 'goToHome' valid syntax?  It seems to simply ignore it since I do not get an error thrown.  Not sure where else the problem could lie...?

Comment: LogContext still the same in your exempla. Please review my answer, and if you call status.setLog in another function, you don`t need to use arrow function. Only call status.setLog.

Comment: I don't know what to tell you other than I find this impossible.  My code as it currently exists has been modified above.  As can be seen I tried to call the 'setLog' to update the object values in two different places...no error is being thrown however the values are not updating either.  Regards,